# How can I insert data to Fuseki server via php with SPARQL QUERY?

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web

> 

```
<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/aungyekyaw/ontologies/2020/8/DL_lib#Book_3">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/aungyekyaw/ontologies/2020/8/DL_lib#Book"/>
    <hasAuthor rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/aungyekyaw/ontologies/2020/8/DL_lib#Ivan_Marsic"/>
    <isInCategory rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/aungyekyaw/ontologies/2020/8/DL_lib#Computer_Science,_Information_and_General_Works"/>
    <description rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Literal">As the author of computer books, I spend a lot of time lurking in the computer section of bookstores, observing the behavior of readers while I’m pretending to read the latest issue of Soap Opera Digest magazine.Because of my research, I’ve learned that if you have picked up this book and turned to this introduction, I only have 13 more seconds before you put it down and head to the coffee bar for a double-tall-decaf-skim-with-two-shots-of-vanilla-hold-the-whip latte.</description>
    <hasISBN rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Literal">ISBN-978-0-672-32990-6</hasISBN>
    <hasTitle rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Software Engineering</hasTitle>
    <locatedIn rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">HEC</locatedIn>
    <published rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime">2012</published>
</owl:NamedIndividual>
```

Above graph was created using protege editor. I want to create like this on web page UI . How can I try. I am a beginner in graph database field. pls...

Comment: SPARQL `INSERT DATA {DATA TRIPLES HERE}` or via SPARQL GRAPH protocol: https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-sparql11-http-rdf-update-20130321/ - both work via HTTP which is trivial with PHP.

Comment: Thank.. would you explain with example?